# SQl Server 2016 with R

Tags: sql-server, r

I have the below Query

```
DECLARE @speedmodel varbinary(max) = (SELECT [model] FROM [dbo].[stopping_distance_models] WHERE model_name = 'latest model');
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
            current_model <- unserialize(as.raw(speedmodel));
            new <- data.frame(NewCarData);
            predicted.distance <- rxPredict(current_model, new);
            str(predicted.distance);
            OutputDataSet <- cbind(new, ceiling(predicted.distance));
            '
    , @input_data_1 = N' SELECT speed FROM [dbo].[NewCarSpeed] '
    , @input_data_1_name = N'NewCarData'
    , @params = N'@speedmodel varbinary(max)'
    , @speedmodel = @speedmodel
WITH RESULT SETS (([new_speed] INT, [predicted_distance] INT))
```

while running this code I got an error message

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 1 A 'R' script error occurred
>   during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT
>   0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 An external script
>   error occurred:  Error in unserialize(as.raw(speedmodel)) : read error
>   Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> unserialize
>
> Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information. Error in
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for
>   more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   .Call Execution halted Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 EXECUTE
>   statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1
>   result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run
>   time.

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like a read error in unserialize call. How was the model serialized and stored in the DB? Can you share this code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you even connect ro your SQL Server DB?

```
library("RODBC")
#library("XLConnect")

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=Name_Of_Server;database=Name_Of_DB;trusted_connection=true')
currTableSQL<-paste("SELECT * From Your_Table",sep="")
currTableDF<-sqlQuery(dbhandle,currTableSQL)
```

Uncomment the XLConnect if you want to utilize that library. I feel like a lot of times if you are using SQL Server, you are using Excel as well.

Or . . .

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=YourServerName; Database=YourDBName;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)
```

Check out these links:

https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/connect-r-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/

Finally, make sure SQL Server has all proper permissions applied.

Comment: How is that at all related to OP's question? OP is using the [R Services in SQL Server 2016/17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/sql-server-r-services) not ODBC connection in R.

Comment: Whoops.  I didn't see anything here about R Services.